# Change format on Business Catalyst web app date string

Tags: date, business-catalyst

I am outputting data from a web app to a list & need to be able to change the date format of data input with the Web App DateTime field.

I am using the web app tag {tag_authorised date}

Comment: What is the output of `{{ item["authorised date"] | json }}` ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a date switch to render the date string in a human-readable format according to your need. The date switch reference can be found [here](https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/reference/liquid/filters.html).

To extend your example, to render 12 March 2018 you would use `{{ this["authorised date"] | date: "%d MMMM yyyy" }}` for a web app detail layout.